# How to unit test my application manually on multiple browsers?

Tags: unit-testing, browser, cross-browser

My project requires support on multiple browsers, like Firefox 2.0, firefox 3.0, IE 6, IE 7, etc. My problem is I cannot test the application on lower versions of the browsers. I have to move to other system or other machines for the testing. Is there any way to solve this?

I cannot even use Virtual Box, since my company won't encourage other softwares to be installed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this really /unit/ testing?

Comment: The web App is supposed to support all the specified browsers as mentioned in the question. So, before check-in, I do a unit testing on all the browsers.

Comment: @hop I think you are right that this is not unit testing, because how could you write unit tests for this in the first place. I think it would be insanely difficult. I think this is what the call black box testing, but please correct me if I am wrong :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are ["Portable" versions of Firefox](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) that will let you test 1.5, 2.0, and 3.0 without much trouble... even from a USB key if the pesky IT folks won't let you install locally.

Answer (score 8):

Use a browser [emulator](http://spellbook.infinitiv.it/2006/07/26/top-10-browser-emulators.htm) such as:

1. [BrowserShots.org](http://browsershots.org) : Free; test your web design in different browsers
2. [iCapture](http://www.danvine.com/icapture/) : Free; safari screenshots
3. [ieCapture](http://www.danvine.com/iecapture/) : Free; internet explorer screenshots
4. [Lynx Viewer](http://www.delorie.com/web/lynxview.html) : Free; this service allows web authors to see what their pages will look like (sort of) when viewed with Lynx, a text-mode web browser.
5. [Browser Cam](http://www.browsercam.com/) : Free for 24 hours; Cross-browser screen captures.
6. [Multiple Internet Explorers](http://www.quirksmode.org/browsers/multipleie.html) : install multiple Internet Explorer versions on the same machine.
7. [Browser Compatibilitytool by NetMechanic](http://www.netmechanic.com/browser-index.htm)  : paid service
8. [Screenshot Generator](http://www.fundisom.com/g5/) : Screenshot generator to see your site on a Macintosh G5 in Safari, MacIE or Mozilla.
9. [Browser Archive](http://browsers.evolt.org/) : Software archive of previous version of browsers at evolt.org

   Source: http://spellbook.infinitiv.it/2006/07/26/top-10-browser-emulators.htm

Answer (score 2):

For IE you can check out [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)

Answer (score 1):

There's a similar question here:
[Running Internet Explorer 6, Internet Explorer 7, and Internet Explorer 8 on the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-on-the-same-machine)

The accepted answer there was to use virtualization so that you can get a true picture of how the website would behave under each browser running on its native system.  You can run firefox on a portable thumbdrive, but you can't do it with IE.  You could put a firefox and an IE on each VM to cut down on the number of VM instances that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Campaign to get VirtualBox installed. Seriously. It's a basic tool for web design. Presumably they give you a better editor than notepad, they owe you decent testing tools as well.

Answer (score 0):

A testing solution depends on the functionality of the application and the resources at your disposal. Your first question should be what platform am I writing on and for? The Operating System platform will determine the default tool set you have.

What is the scope of the application?

-Are you testing graphical elements?
-GUI IO?
 
-Computational functionality?

Will you have access to:

- Virtual Machine(s) - one computer emulating other environments
- Use Multiple local machines and a KVM Switch, more raw processing power, easy access, works well for GUI testing
- Use multiple remote machines via SSH or some other server-client arrangement, a client like VNC or a form of remote desktop might be required .

You will require an automated method of application installation, activation, reset and reporting. Can you run scripts or batchfiles? Must the app run in a GUI mode, does it have a CLI? Do you have access to other services such as web servers, can you open ports to send/receive status reports? Can you remotely login to the test machines, launch and reset the browsers from the command line?. Can you reset a hung Application?

Failure and success can be reported in various ways such as the creation of a local file, the downloading of an image from a server or a ping on a port. Essentially testing will require more work and time because you will need to design, implement and perhaps ironically test a testing suite and apparatus.

Answer (score 0):

To Check All IE
You can go to CodeckPack . nl and install all IE, ie, [IE collection](http://codecpack.nl/iecollection.htm).

or you can use www. multibrowserviewer .com it can check in 45 browsers and 3 os